# Stream video from raspberry pi to andriod unity app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi, usb, webcam

At school, we are busy with a project where we need to have 2 camera input's connected to an android phone with a unity application running.

At the moment we have the idea to use some USB webcams and plug those into a raspberry pi. This has been done before. But the part that we are not really sure about is how we can connect the raspberry pi to an android phone and transfer the video.

[Here is a schematic of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlviQ.jpg). The idea is that we want to simulate different kinds of vision of animals in a google cardboard experience.

The part I'm not sure about is the connection to the android phone and unity. The USB webcams to raspberry shouldn't make a problem.

I hope someone can give an answer or point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance,

Bastien Olivier Dijkstra

Comment: If someone is still looking for solution, there is a youtube demo of cross-platform live streaming using FM Exhibition Tool Pack. https://youtu.be/i7ljqutWke8

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a neat project.  Are you setting it up so each camera gives the view for each eye (hence the 3D aspect)?

For starters, if you simply want static images, you can try to SCP or FTP the resultant video files to your android.

[AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp&hl=en_US) does a pretty good job of FTP for Android devices.

On the other hand, if you want to watch a live stream of the video from the RaspiCam, you can do that also with a myriad of other apps, but I personally use [IP Cam Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rcreations.ipcamviewer&hl=en_US) to view the RTSP stream.

You will basically be viewing each RTSP stream independently.  You may need to adjust the viewing resolution so it doesn't overload your RPi, but [Unity can deal with up to eight cameras and up to eight viewing 'screens'](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html).

Comment: I have updated my question with some more specifics. And is it possible to use an application like IP Cam Viewer with Unity?